# how to call an element from an array depends on the condition

Tags: arrays, c

I have to write a function that recalls the lowest prices depending on the order the customer prefers (the lowest, the second lowest and etc.) but I'm having a hard time trying to summon the right elements from the arrays.

```
int lowestPrice(int array[], int size, int order){

int tempArray[size];

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int swapped = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++){
        
        if(array[i] > array[i+1]){
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = temp;

            swapped = 1;
        }

        int j=0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        
            if (array[i] != array[i+1]){
                tempArray[j] = array[i];
            }j++;
        } tempArray[j] = array[i - 1];

    }
        if (swapped == 0){
            
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                printf("%d\t", array[i]);

            }break;
        }
}    



}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking, please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Consider indenting your C code with  [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/), then compile it with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. You probably need to use [calloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html) then `free` for your `tempArray`. You certainly should spend a few hours reading a good [C programming book](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/c-programming-books/). You may want to use [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: @kan3 This declaration int tempArray[]; is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your condition is order as I guessed, here is how you can do that :

```
int lowestPrice(int array[], int size, int order){
// if you want to keep the same order in your initial array copy it in a new one:
// you can do that with memcpy as well but i asume you can't...
    int tempArray[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tempArray[i] = array[i];
// Then sort it :
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (size_t j = i; j < size; j++)
            if (tempArray[j] < tempArray[i]) {
                int tmp = tempArray[i];
                tempArray[i] = tempArray[j];
                tempArray[j] = tmp;
            }
// Return the one you want with order (order from the lowest to the highest):
    return tempArray[order];
}
```